# How to replace text in css?

Tags: css, css-transitions

### I was taking a test in fiverr. There I got the following question:

```
Consider the following code:
body{text-replace: "a" "b" "b" "c"}
```

---

### What will be the output of the following string if the text replace style is implemented?

```
 1. ndy lives behind cbfe
 2. cndy lives cehind ccfe
 3. andy lives behind cafe
 4. andy lives cehind bafe
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is #2:

```
“cndy lives cehind ccfe”
```

The exact CSS sample appears in the spec, linked above, and the example is described as follows (emphasis mine):

> *The two rules below yield the same result. **In the first rule all ‘a’ characters are converted to ‘b’. Subsequently, all ‘b’ characters
> are converted to ‘c’.** In the second rule, all ‘a’ and ‘b’ characters
> are converted directly to ‘c’.*
>
> ```
> body { text-replace: "a" "b" "b" "c" }
> body { text-replace: "a" "c" "b" "c" }
> ```

So the processing order goes:

```
 1. andy lives behind cafe
 2. bndy lives behind cbfe
 3. cndy lives cehind ccfe
```